# How to write this JavaScript code without eval (QUnit mocking)?

Tags: javascript, mocking, eval, qunit

I've been experimenting with QUnit tests and was looking for a good method to override functions with mocks so as to enable more atomic tests. There are good solutions out there for specific cases, for example overriding $.ajax ([Simple jQuery (1.5+) AJAX Mocking](https://gist.github.com/1371254)), but I was looking for a more general approach and came up with this:

```
// Constructor for overrides.
function overrides(overrides) {
    this.overrides = overrides;
}

// Implementation for overrides.
overrides.prototype = {
    set: function () {
        var functions = {};
        $.each(this.overrides, function (key, value) {
            eval("functions['" + key + "'] = " + key + ";");
            eval(key + " = value;");
        });
        this.functions = functions;
    },

    reset: function () {
        var functions = this.functions;
        $.each(this.overrides, function (key, _) {
            eval(key + " = functions['" + key + "'];");
        });
    }
}
```

Which can then be used like:

```
module("Comments", {
    setup: function () {
        this.overrides = new overrides({ "$.ajax": function (url, options) {
            alert("ajax: " + url + ', ' + options);
        }
        });

        this.overrides.set();
    },
    teardown: function () {
        this.overrides.reset();
    }
});
```

Now, that all appears to work fine, and although this may not be the worst possible use of eval(), I was wondering if this could indeed be written without using eval()? I've read up on a bunch of the other eval() questions here and tried various options like accessing the overrides using window[] but that does not work for the $.ajax case for example (window['$'].ajax works but not window['$.ajax']).

Perhaps I'm also thinking to hard and eval() can be used safely here or there is a better approach in general for function overrides?

Comment: Made changed based on the answers below and posted eval() free version [here](https://gist.github.com/1553139).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just treat the objects as objects?

```
functions[key] = key;

var arr = key.split('.');
var obj = window;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if (obj) obj = obj[arr[i]];
}

obj = value;
```

Comment: `key = value` is not the same as `eval(key + '= value')`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the OP wants; `window['$.ajax']` won't actually overwrite `$.ajax`.

Comment: @pimvdb: see my updated code. It might work the way the OP intended.

Comment: @Chris: I'm trying to `split()` the key into a chain of properties.

Comment: @Blender: A few more tweaks appears to be necessary: only loop to `(arr.length - 1)` and then set the value as `obj[arr[i]] = value`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way as far as I know is providing the object and property name separately. This is also the case with native functions such as `Object.defineProperty`, which takes the object as one argument and the property name as a string as another argument.

```
// overwrite properties inside `$`

new overrides($, {"ajax": function (url, options) {
    alert("ajax: " + url + ', ' + options);
}});
```

And something like this:

```
function overrides(obj, overrides) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.overrides = overrides;
}
```

and:

```
set: function () {
    var functions = {};
    var inst = this;

    $.each(this.overrides, function (key, value) {
        functions[key] = inst.obj[key]; // old function
        inst.obj[key] = value; // overwrite function
    });

    this.functions = functions;
},
```

It works because `inst.obj` and `$` refer to the same object - changing properties on `inst.obj` modifies `$` as well in this case.